# Usernotes in ios

Tags: xcode, storyboard, uiactionsheet, alertview, notesview

[image]I want to create a user note form in my application,currently am using one textview inside a view its looking bad !! is there any other control suits for this purpose?  Main aim is when user click the button a small textview will appear they can add comments there and save it into plist.
[image]    I want something like this(check the  image)

i want that kind of usernotes (its my image) please give me some advices and helps to develop this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `UIAlertView` with `UITextView` can be useful for you.

Implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` in .h file.

```
UITextView *comments;

-(IBAction)btnAddClicked:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Noreply Email" message:@"\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:@"Send", nil];
    comments = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,45, 255, 100)];
    [comments setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mailbody.png"]]];
    [comments setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:15]];
    comments.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [comments becomeFirstResponder];
    [alert addSubview:comments];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Here alert will be prompted with small textview you can add comments and then handle text inside delegate method like this.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==1) //Send button pressed
    {
        //handle your comment here
        NSLog(@"%@",comments.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: :According to iOs development we cannot use AlertView for user input

Comment: Where have read this ? Many of us using alert for input.  Even http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html UIAlertView it self has  UIAlertViewStyleSecureTextInput, UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput, UIAlertViewStyleLoginAndPasswordInput styles for input.

Comment: They all saying about displaying contents

Comment: the same link ...https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html