# How to Read Plist without using NSDictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, nsdictionary

I've already used this method in Swift 2

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist") {
myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
```

But don't know how to read plist in Swift3 without using 
**NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)**

Comment: what is your question? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: need swift3 conversion for above code

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The native Swift way is to use `PropertyListSerialization`

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Config", withExtension: "plist") {
   do {
     let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
     let swiftDictionary = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
      // do something with the dictionary
   } catch {
      print(error)
   }
}
```

You can also use `NSDictionary(contentsOf:` with a type cast:

```
if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"Config", withExtension: "plist"),
   let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: url) as? [String:Any] {
   print(myDict)
}
```

but you explicitly wrote: *without using NSDictionary(contentsOf...*

Basically don't use `NSDictionary` without casting in Swift, you are throwing away the important type information.

---

Meanwhile (Swift 4+) there is still more comfortable `PropertyListDecoder` which is able to decode Plist directly into a model.

Comment: So to use Dictionary in native way, I have to use **PropertyListSerialization** right

Comment: @vadian I'd add that `import Foundation` is necessary for this to work under native `Swift`.

Comment: @dinesharjani Yes, it is, but `Foundation` is necessary for `Data` and `PropertyListSerialization`, too, so we can assume it's imported anyway.

Comment: @vadian if you're doing a server-side project like `Perfect`, `Foundation` will not be automatically imported for you :)

My thought process here is to catch the "copy-paste-doesn't work-keep googling" kind of guy (or gal) who'll go in circles because they'll miss the import. That's all.

Answer (score 6):

**PropertyListDecoder** can be used to decode plist file directly to Objects.

**1: Sample Plist File (sample.plist)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>key1</key>
    <string>valua for key1</string>
    <key> key2</key>
    <string>valua for key1</string>
    <key>CustomClass1</key>
    <dict>
        <key>customClass1_key</key>
        <string>customClass1_value</string>
    </dict>
    <key>CustomClass2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>customClass2_kek</key>
        <string>customClasse_value</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**2: Corresponding Models for plist**

```
struct PlistConfiguration: Codable {
    var key1:String?
    var customClass1Obj: CustomClass1?
    var customClass2Obj: CustomClass2?
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case key1 = "key1"
        case customClass1Obj = "CustomClass1"
        case customClass2Obj = "CustomClass2"
    }
}
```

**2.1: Nested Model**

```
struct CustomClass1: Codable {
    var customClass1_key:String?
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case customClass1_key = "customClass1_key"
    }
}
```

**2.2: Nested Model**

```
struct CustomClass2: Codable {
    var customClass2_key: String?
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
        case customClass2_key = "customClass2_key"
    }
}
```

**3: Read Plist from main app bundle**

```
func parseConfig() -> PlistConfiguration {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sample", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode(PlistConfiguration.self, from: data)
}
```

Comment: You saved my time. But .. shouldn't the return of parseConfig() be PlistConfiguration instead of SKDConfiguration?

Answer (score 1):

In a modern Swift environment I use stuff like this:

```swift
import Foundation

public extension Bundle {

  func plist<As>(from resource: String) -> As? where As: Decodable {
    guard let plist = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resource, withExtension: "plist") else { return nil }
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    do {
      let data = try Data(contentsOf: plist)
      return try decoder.decode(As.self, from: data)
    } catch { return nil }
  }

}
```