# Converting objective-c codes to swift 4

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

it's been 1.5 years i've been writing in `obj-c`, its a good language.. so i saw a medium article today about swift, really looking onto it, right now i am trying to convert all my `obj-c` codes to `swift`, fortunately everything is done expect for this part..

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"list" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSArray *plistData = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

    NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"english ==[c] %@", self.userQuery.text]; // something like "Abbey"
    NSArray *filtered = [plistData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];



    NSLog(@"found matches: %@ : %@", filtered,[filtered valueForKey:@"kurdi"]);

    if (filtered.count>0) {
        NSDictionary *dic  = filtered[0];
        self.theMeaningLabel.text = dic[@"kurdi"];


    } else {
         self.theMeaningLabel.text = @"Yay!‌";
    }
```

i am not being able to properly convert this into the new `swift 4`, it gives random errors

## EDIT

after a few searches, i could just write two lines of code
here's my swift code

```
    var path: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "list", ofType: "plist")
    var plistData = [Any](contentsOfFile: path!)
    var filter = NSPredicate(format: "english ==[c] %@", searchText)
    // something like "Abbey"
    var filtered = plistData?.filter { filter.evaluate(with: $0) }
    print("found matches: \(filtered) : \(filtered?.value(forKey: "kurdi"))")
    if filtered?.count > 0 {
        var dic = filtered[0]
       // theMeaningLabel.text = dic["kurdi"]
    }
    else {
        //theMeaningLabel.text = "Yay!‌"
    }
```

but getting the

> Argument labels '(contentsOfFile:)' do not match any available overloads

## Final edit

```
 var path = Bundle.main.path(forResource:"list", ofType: "plist")
var plistData = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

let filter = NSPredicate(format: "english ==[c] %@", searchText)
var filtered = plistData?.filtered(using: filter)
// [error 9:10] no viable alternative at input 'NSLog(@"found matches: %@ : %@"'
if filtered?.count > 0 {
    var dic = filtered![0]
   // theMeaningLabel.text = dic["kurdi"]
}
else {
   // theMeaningLabel.text = "Yay!‌"
}
```

the code above is fine, but one error comes

```
if filtered?.count > 0 { // here
    var dic = filtered![0]
   // theMeaningLabel.text = dic["kurdi"]
}
else {
   // theMeaningLabel.text = "Yay!‌"
}
```

getting

> Binary operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int?' and 'Int'

Comment: Don’t show the Objective-C, show the Swift and the errors you are getting.

Comment: @Paulw11, actually can't get my head around it, stuck in the predicate format, waiting for someone to give a proper clean code

Comment: The predicate format is exactly the same since that is part of the foundation library, not Swift or Objective-C.

Comment: `let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "english ==[c] %@", searchText)` , yeah i got this but the line after this is complex

Comment: If you are still using `NSArray` then the next line is essentially the same too.

Comment: @Paulw11, just updated the question

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar you can use https://objectivec2swift.com/#/converter/ for converting your objective c code into swift.

Comment: @KAR, thank you, but i don't think that this site would be that much smart, so updated the question, the one i converted with them returns an error too

Comment: you had the right code before using `Data`.

Comment: @Paulw11, same property list

Comment: @RawandAhmedShaswar is `plistData` is array of keypair?

Comment: @Jack, question updated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use native Swift way to Read Plist in Swift 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436895/how-to-use-native-swift-way-to-read-plist-in-swift-3)

Comment: @VishalPatel, do not mark questions without truly reading both sides, you gave a wrong code, i appreciate it, but this is not a duplicate, i solved it myself !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A literal translation from Objective-C to Swift is not recommended because in many cases it does not take advantage of the improved semantics of Swift.

As Apple removed all path manipulating API from `String` and added more `URL` related API to other classes use always `URL` if possible

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "list", withExtension: "plist")!
```

The forced unwrapped url is safe since the file is required to be in the bundle. A crash will reveal a design error and must not happen at runtime.

---

Unlike the Foundation collection types the Swift collection types don't support the implicit property list conversion so the Swift way is to use `Data` and `PropertyListSerialization`

```
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let dataArray = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [Any]
```

The forced `try!` is as safe as forced unwrapping the `url` for the same reasons.

`[Any]` is the most unspecified Swift Array. If the array is supposed to be an array of dictionaries write `[[String:Any]]` or even `[[String: String]]` if all values are `String`. If it's supposed to be an array of Strings write `[String]`. Swift encourages the developer to be as type specific as possible.

---

An `NSPredicate` can be replaced with the `filter` function in Swift. For example an array of strings can be filtered case insensitively with

```
let filtered = dataArray.filter { $0.compare(searchText, options:.caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame }
```

If the array contains dictionaries you need to specify the keys (same as `NSPredicate)`

```
let filtered = dataArray.filter { ($0["foo"] as! String).compare(searchText, options:.caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame }
```

---

Finally the ObjC expression

```
 if (filtered.count > 0) { ...
```

can be written much more descriptive in Swift

```
 if filtered.isEmpty == false { ...
```

or

```
 if !filtered.isEmpty { ...
```

If you are looking for only one item you can even write

```
if let foundObject = dataArray.first(where: { $0.compare(searchText, options:.caseInsensitive) == .orderedSame }) { ...
```

Comment: the last time i had a problem with obj-c you helped, and again, sof needs more people like you