# Alternative to the objective-NSDictionary(contentsOfFile) method in swift

Tags: swift, swift3, plist

I am trying to parse a plist.

The code snippet is given below:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: Constants.plistName,    ofType: Constants.plistType) {

       guard let myDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) else {
           //throw some error
       } }
```

If I set the type of myDictionary to Dictionary, I can no longer use the contentsOfFile method. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The (recommended) alternative is `PropertyListSerialization`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: Constants.plistName, withExtension: Constants.plistType)!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let myDictionary = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
```

Comment: Why are you casting it to a Dictionary of key type string and value type any?

Comment: You answered an identical question before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40437034/1187415.

Comment: Because all keys of a property list dictionary are required to be `String` and the common type of all supported value types is `Any` – @MartinR Thanks for marking as duplicate. Your memory is much better than mine ;)