# Delete a key from a plist

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have a commandline tool written in swift that edits xcode project settings.

I need to be able to delete a 'key' from the .entitlements file.

The specific situation is that I have some projects that do not support associated domains but I need to remove the whole

```
    <key>com.apple.developer.associated-domains</key>
<array>
    <string>applinks:xxx.page.link</string>
</array>
```

from the file in a gracefull way because leaving just the array empty means the project indicates using associated domains and it does not.

so in short using swift remove a key from a plist.

Comment: The best way must be to load the whole list into memory, delete the key/data and write it back to file. See for instance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40436895/how-to-read-plist-without-using-nsdictionary-in-swift

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution would be using PlistBuddy.

You'll have to launch a shell command with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26973384/3393964

The command would be something like:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c 'Delete :com.apple.developer.associated-domains' Info.plist
```